# Find averages across different date time ranges

Tags: mysql

I have a database table `results` with a number of columns, showing a running count of how many goals have been scored at each minute.

e.g.

```
f_total_ftg    # full time goals
f_total_htg    # half time goals
f_total_1mg    # 1 minute goals
```

Each insert in the database has a column `f_datetime`, which is the associated timestamp.

I'm trying to get an average of each goal column and then take the overall avg and last 2 weeks average and divide by 2.

Example:

```
f_avg_total_ftg_overall = 3.12
f_avg_total_ftg_last_2_weeks = 2.42

f_avg_ftg = (f_avg_total_ftg_overall + f_avg_total_ftg_last_2_weeks) / 2
```

My current solution is to take each column overall/last 2 weeks separately, returning a dict in my python code where I do the end calculation, but this should be doable in one query I think.

What I currently have:

```
SELECT AVG((SELECT AVG(f_total_ftg) as x FROM results WHERE f_datetime < '2020-07-01 01:30:00')) AS ft_x,
         AVG((SELECT AVG(f_total_ftg) as x FROM results WHERE f_datetime between '2020-07-01 01:30:00' - INTERVAL 13 DAY AND '2020-07-01 01:30:00')) AS ft_y,
         
         AVG((SELECT AVG(f_total_1mg) as x FROM results WHERE f_datetime < '2020-07-01 01:30:00')) AS 1m_x,
         AVG((SELECT AVG(f_total_1mg) as x FROM results WHERE f_datetime between '2020-07-01 01:30:00' - INTERVAL 13 DAY AND '2020-07-01 01:30:00')) AS 1m_y,   

         AVG((SELECT AVG(f_total_htg) as x FROM results WHERE f_datetime < '2020-07-01 01:30:00')) AS ht_total,
         AVG((SELECT AVG(f_total_htg) as x FROM results WHERE f_datetime between '2020-07-01 01:30:00' - INTERVAL 13 DAY AND '2020-07-01 01:30:00')) AS ht_last14d
         
 FROM results
```

How can I simplify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can be simplified with conditional aggregation like this:

```
SELECT 
  AVG(CASE WHEN f_datetime < '2020-07-01 01:30:00' THEN f_total_ftg END) AS ft_x,
  AVG(CASE WHEN f_datetime BETWEEN '2020-07-01 01:30:00' - INTERVAL 13 DAY AND '2020-07-01 01:30:00' THEN f_total_ftg END) AS ft_y,
  AVG(CASE WHEN f_datetime < '2020-07-01 01:30:00' THEN f_total_1mg END) AS 1m_x,
  AVG(CASE WHEN f_datetime BETWEEN '2020-07-01 01:30:00' - INTERVAL 13 DAY AND '2020-07-01 01:30:00' THEN f_total_1mg END) AS 1m_y,
  AVG(CASE WHEN f_datetime < '2020-07-01 01:30:00' THEN f_total_htg END) AS ht_total,
  AVG(CASE WHEN f_datetime BETWEEN '2020-07-01 01:30:00' - INTERVAL 13 DAY AND '2020-07-01 01:30:00' THEN f_total_htg END) AS ht_last14d
FROM results
```

Also the query could be further simplified to:

```
SELECT 
  AVG(f_total_ftg) AS ft_x,
  AVG(CASE WHEN f_datetime >= '2020-07-01 01:30:00' - INTERVAL 13 DAY THEN f_total_ftg END) AS ft_y,
  AVG(f_total_1mg) AS 1m_x,
  AVG(CASE WHEN f_datetime >= '2020-07-01 01:30:00' - INTERVAL 13 DAY THEN f_total_1mg END) AS 1m_y,
  AVG(f_total_htg) AS ht_total,
  AVG(CASE WHEN f_datetime >= '2020-07-01 01:30:00' - INTERVAL 13 DAY THEN f_total_htg END) AS ht_last14d
FROM results
WHERE f_datetime <= '2020-07-01 01:30:00'
```

if you included the `=` in the inequality `<= '2020-07-01 01:30:00'` of your `CASE` expressions.

Now you can select from it and do your calculations:

```
SELECT ft_x, ft_Y, 1m_x, 1m_y, ht_total, ht_last14d, 
       (ht_total + ht_last14d) / 2,
       ...........................
FROM (
  <the query here>
) t
```

I'm not sure that `(ht_total + ht_last14d) / 2` is what you need but I think you get the idea.